# Difference between angular2/core and @angular/core

Tags: typescript, angular

Might be very stupid but I have seen several uses of

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
```

and

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
```

but  I am not able to understand when to use one or another.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the first release candidate the packages are repackaging into individual packages.  There is now one package for each feature area.

```
angular2/core (before rc.0) -> @angular/core (>= rc.0)
```

Answer (score 6):

Angular2 team has repackaged Angular and all those packages are distributed under **@Angular** npm scope.

Read here more from official docs and check various changed paths with RC relase, https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md (2.0.0-rc.0 (2016-05-02))

**#** When Angular2 was going through **Beta Releases**, we used import various symbols from **`angular2/core`**.

**#** Now Angular2 is going through **Release candidate**(RC), we have to import various symbols from **`@angular/core`**.

Answer (score 2):

`import {Component} from 'angular2/core'` for versions **`<= beta.x`**

`import {Component} from '@angular/core'` for **`>= RC.x`**