# cannot find module '@angular/core' in Visual Studio Code IDE

Tags: angular, typescript

Pretty simple code. But having the error `cannot find module '@angular/core'`.

**course.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'


@Component({
    selector: 'courses'
})
export class CoursesComponent{

}
```

**typings.json**

```
 {
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts#6697d6f7dadbf5773cb40ecda35a76027e0783b2"
 }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
   "exclude": [
   "node_modules",
   "typings/main",
   "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
   "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
   "tsc": "tsc",
   "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
   "lite": "lite-server",
   "typings": "typings",
   "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
   "license": "ISC",
   "dependencies": {
   "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.7",
   "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
   "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
   "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
   "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
   "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
   "systemjs": "0.19.22",
   "zone.js": "0.5.15"
  },
 "devDependencies": {
  "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
  "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
   "typescript": "^1.7.5"
  }
}
```

I know this kind of question has been answered many times. But due to my ignorance, I still don't know.

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**

My files are organized as[image: capture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally I downloaded the quick start seed from a course on udemy.com. Obviously the course was old. And something was mess up. I have to remind the instructor to correct it

Now I re-download the quick start from angular web site. The files structure is completely different from my original one. For example, it has a `e2e` folder and `tslint.json`. The `package.json` file is under thr root folder etc.  `tsconfig.json` is in `src` folder.

A lot of changes, now it is working. Thanks everybody's hint.

Answer (score 5):

For me it was due to the typescript module not selected correctly. So I selected same module value of "tsconfig.json File ->  compilerOptions -> module: commonjs " at visual studio project properties.  [image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your dependencies are using the package naming before RC versions.

This is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37510060/1729041). In short, you need to add `@angular/core` (and the rest of the dependencies) in the `package.json`

EDIT:
`package.json`

```
{
    "name": "angular2-quickstart",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
        "tsc": "tsc",
        "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
        "lite": "lite-server",
        "typings": "typings",
        "postinstall": "typings install"
    },
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "<your desired angular version>",
        "@angular/compiler": "<your desired angular version>",
        "@angular/core": "<your desired angular version>",
        "@angular/forms": "<your desired angular version>",
        "@angular/http": "<your desired angular version>",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "<your desired angular version>",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "<your desired angular version>",
        "@angular/router": "<your desired angular version>",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
        "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
        "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
        "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
        "systemjs": "0.19.22",
        "zone.js": "0.5.15"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
        "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
        "typescript": "^1.7.5"
    }
}
```

On the Angular QuickStart [`package.json`](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/package.json) you have a clear picture of this example. Please, devote some time on the docs to make customizations according to your Angular version.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not sure how to do it. Please explain it with code, What I have to do in package.json?

Comment: `@angular/core` name change appeared after the beta versions (RC and final). What Angular version are you changing to?

Comment: The question is that even I downloaded the [quick start](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) and run `npm start`. It still throws the error.

Comment: Silly question, did you try to run `npm install` after changing the `package.json`?

Comment: No, I just get rid of all. And download a fresh quick-start.Try to run it.

Comment: Following the guide of the Quickstart [`README`](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) this was the outcome: http://imgur.com/a/VTsHB

Answer (score 1):

To me on Ionic 3 project, works just updating the typescript to the latest version

```
npm i --save-dev typescript@latest
```

Then, run:

```
npm update
```

If you have problems with `ionic serve`, just run:

```
npm install
```

To see more details on how to adjust VSCode IDE to "hide" this problem, see: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_using-newer-typescript-versions

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error but the solution was different for me, so I'll post here for anyone else that may have the same issue. I had cloned a repository from GitHub and I had this error and other similar errors on my import statements. I figured there were some files missing since there was a .gitignore. I ran the command `npm install` and it installed missing packages/files. It also resolved the error "No projects support the 'build' target" when trying to run npm build.

Answer (score 0):

That problem can be arised only if there doesn't exist any such file or folder So, please Look for a folder named "node_modules" which should be present at the same place where your package.json, tsconfig.json exists and then follow this
 node_modules-> @angular -> core

Comment: this edit is not of much use, just look inside your `node_modules` and search for `@angular` folder

Comment: There is a `angular2` folder inside `node_modules`. There is `core.js` inside angular2 folder.

Comment: If you are importing from `@angular/core` then there has to be a folder named `@angular` in `node_modules` and into that `@angular` there has to be a folder named `core`